# One .exe showing different file versions

Tags: file, compiler-construction, linker, version, exe

We have compiled a fresh version of our software.
Yesterday we (accidentally) revealed that it is showing us different file (and product) versions depending on the machine you're looking at it.

If we look at it from the developer (virtual) machine it is showing the new file version. Even if it has not been compiled with "this" machine.

If we look at it from a host or different client it is showing an old version. It doesn't mind if you use the windows explorer or any different tool.

If you copy it from the virtual machine to the host - it magically changes its version.

The only OS difference between the Host and the VM is the language. The Host-OS is german, the VM-OS is english.

Has anybody an idea how this can be?

P.S.: Checked the files inside and outside the VM with a HexEditor and Resource Edtior and the new version number seems to be correctly in the file.

Comment: This clearly shows that you are in fact looking at different files. Most likely the file is "installed" twice on the second system.

Comment: Is one of version values bigger than 65535?

Answer (score 0):

It showed up that the included resources had different versions for different languages. Didn't know that this is possible up to now.